# Making an API call using WebClient inside of a Controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

So I've got a simple `@RestController` endpoint, in which I want to make an API call out, using WebClient, and then take the data I got from that call, make some more API calls, process data, and eventually return with some data based on all that...

However, this whole reactive thing is messing me up.  I get how to do this in the old way with `RestTemplate`, no problem... and I would have figured that this would be exactly the time to use `block()` to wait for the client to finish and then I can use that data, but apparently this isn't allowed inside of a "reactive" controller!

I've created a custom POJO (`ExternalApiResponse`) that matches the JSON data response from the API, which seems to be working fine... The following code works with no errors, and perfectly responds with the JSON data from the API call and displays it in the browser after it's fetched from the external API...

This `ExternalApiResponse` actually contains just a single `List` of another POJO, since the results from the API call are formatted like `{ [ ] }` (is there a better way to do that?), meaning an array wrapped in an object... I don't want to just return the API results, I want to iterate through them and even make an additional API call (elsewhere) for each element in the initially returned API results, then returning with a new object that has been processed!

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping
public class Controller {
  @RequestMapping("/{id}")
  public Mono<ExternalApiResponse> queryApi(@PathVariable String id) {
    Mono<ExternalApiResponse> response = webClientBuilder.build()
    .get()
    .uri(uri)
    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .retrieve()
    .bodyToMono(ExternalApiResponse.class)
    
    return response;

  }
}
```

I presume there's a more appropriate way to structure this, but I'm just not sure.  Any leads are much appreciated!

Comment: I presume the solution will be to use either `map()` or `flatMap()`, but every attempt I've made to do so has failed!  :/

Comment: flatMap the mono, get the list from the object throw it into a Flux.fromIterable, then flatMap again each item emitted from the flux. In that flatMap do a new webclient call for each item.

Comment: Using `flatMap` will simply merge/flatten every response you retrieve along the way. But, you said "_make some more API calls, process data, and eventually return with some data based on all that_" - which implies `flatMap` might actually be the wrong approach. Perhaps you should simply `subscribe()` to the Mono, then make an API call, `subscribe()` to that one, and on and on it goes until you've mangled to data. Finally return the result from each `subscribe()` to have it bubble all the way back the client.

Comment: I was reading that subscribe shouldn't be used here, is that not correct?  I'm seriously at a loss for the right syntax here, I can't figure out how to extract the List (or array, I've tried both) from the single response using flatMap or map!  A little syntax example would go a long way here to making my day!

Comment: This seems to work to extract the collection into it's own Mono of the CollectionType...

Mono<CollectionType[]> collect = response.map(c -> c.getCollection());

But then I don't know what to do with it to to iterate through them!

Answer (score 0):

```java
@RequestMapping("/{id}")
public Mono<MyApiResponse> queryApi(@PathVariable String id) {
    return webClientBuilder
        .build()
        .get()
        .uri(uri)
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(ExternalApiResponse.class)
        .flatMapIterable(externalApiResponse -> externalApiResponse.getList()) // switch to flux
        .flatMap(item -> process(item)) // process each item individually
        .collectList() // collect processed items into a list to wrap them
        .map(processedItems -> new MyApiResponse(processedItems)); // wrap
}

private Mono<ProcessedItem> process(Item item) {
    // todo
}

private static class ExternalApiResponse {
    List<Item> list;
}

private static class MyApiResponse {
    List<ProcessedItem> processedItems;
}
```